# How to access shell variable of one context on other shell's context

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I have executed following command on shell

```
sw0:root> pwd
/root
sw0:root> echo $(history 1)
2 echo $(history 1)
sw0:root>
```

Now i call system system call in a c file as shown below

```
system (" echo \"___history1 = $(history 1)____\"");
```

Output:

```
___history1 = ____
```

What i have tried is i try to read the last history command of a shell from C using `system` system call.

Please clarify following doubts

1. Why i'm unable to read last history command executed in shell from c file?
2. Is it because when i call system system call,it forks  a new shell?
3. If so, how do i achieve this? Reading command output of 1 shell from other?

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program, it runs in a subshell and does not inherit the history of the calling shell.

You can compare this to running `bash -c history`, you get no result.

Comment: Gauthier,so is there anyway i could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You open  shell:1 now perfrom some commands.
Now close that shell.

After that open new shell2 and use that `system()` command it will have that information of commands executated in shell1

---

**Untill you close current shell, its history is not flushed in global history file.**

Yes system will open its own context.

---

> OP: i executed this command on main shell that runs from the bootup of
>   the system,so is there any way i could manually flush it?

For that you need to add this line in your .bashrc file

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

see: http://www.aloop.org/2012/01/19/flush-commands-to-bash-history-immediately/

Comment: Mr, i executed this command on main shell that runs from the bootup of the system,so is there any way i could manually flush it?

Comment: @user3446120 Updated my answer for that

Comment: Mr.32, My PROMPT_COMMAND already points to some script,it cannot be changed. Is there anyway i could switch from this shell to that shell?

Comment: export PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND:'history -a' this way you can add more value in that variable...

Comment: Mr.32,i tried that too its not flushing,is there any way i can switch from one shell context to other?

Comment: after that change did you restart ./bashrc ? You need to restart bashrc to make changes in effect

Comment: Yes i did,there was no changes o/p was same

Comment: system() command starts .sh sell where we updated settings in bash so make some settings such that your run history command in bash or in sh shell change the settings of history command